# Caching client side code results across pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, cookies, local-storage

In our application, we are painting **navigation component** using JavaScript/jQuery and because of authorization, this involves complex logic.

Navigation component is required on almost all authenticated pages, hence whenever user navigates from one page to another, **the complex logic is repeated on every page**.

I am sure that under particular conditions the results of such complex calculations will not change for a certain period, hence I feel recalculation is unnecessary under those conditions.

So I want to **store/cache the results at browser/client side**. One of the solution I feel would be creating a ***cookie*** with the results.

I need suggestions if it is a good approach. If not, what else can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

If you can rely on modern browsers HTML 5 web strorage options are a good bet.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage
Quote from above

> There are several reasons to use client-side storage. First, you can
>   make your app work when the user is offline, possibly sync'ing data
>   back once the network is connected again. Second, it's a performance
>   booster; you can show a large corpus of data as soon as the user
>   clicks on to your site, instead of waiting for it to download again.
>   Third, it's an easier programming model, with no server infrastructure
>   required. Of course, the data is more vulnerable and the user can't
>   access it from multiple clients, so you should only use it for
>   non-critical data, in particular cached versions of data that's also
>   "in the cloud". See "Offline": What does it mean and why should I
>   care? for a general discussion of offline technologies, of which
>   client-side storage is one component.

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
{
  // this will store and retrieve key / value for the browser session
  sessionStorage.setItem('your_key', 'your_value');
  sessionStorage.getItem('your_key');

  // this will store and retrieve key / value permanently for the domain
  localStorage.setItem('your_key', 'your_value');
  localStorage.getItem('your_key');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you can try HTML 5 Local Storage or Web SQL, you can have more options in it.Web SQL support is very less when compared to Local Storage. Have a look on this http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html